# Cannot Validate data using Fluent Validation in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have been trying to validate data using the FluentValidation Library in asp.net core,but I just can't seem to make it work.I have created different class for model where the data I want to validate is located,controller and validation but The flow of the program just doesn't pass throught the validation.The validation is working with Attribute Validation so there is no problem with connection with database
How Can I  make this happen?

Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<NewFatcaContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
           .AddFluentValidation(s =>
           {
               s.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true; 
             s.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<BankParamsValidator>();
            
           });
    }
```

Model class

```
 public class ResponseModel
{
    public ResponseModel()
    {
        IsValid = true;
        ValidationMessages = new List<string>();
    }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public List<string> ValidationMessages { get; set; }
}
public partial class tblBankParams
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30,MinimumLength =5)]
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller class

```
        public class BankParamsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly NewFatcaContext _context;
    //private IValidator<tblBankParams> _validator; //18
   // private ItblBankParamsRepository _repository;  //18

    public BankParamsController(NewFatcaContext context)
        {
         // private  _validator = validator; //18
       // _repository = tb   //18
            
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<tblBankParams> bankParams = _context.tblBankParams.ToList();
            return View(bankParams);
        }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Edit(int Id)
       
    {
      tblBankParams bankParams = _context.tblBankParams.Where(p => p.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
      return View(bankParams);
        
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(tblBankParams bankParams)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Attach(bankParams);
            _context.Entry(bankParams).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
            return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
}
```

Validation class

```
 public class BankParamsValidator : AbstractValidator<tblBankParams>
{


    public BankParamsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Value).Matches("US").When(d => d.Id == 3).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Value).Length(2, 2).When(d => d.Id == 2).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Value).Matches("FATCA").When(d => d.Id == 6).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Value must be only fatca");
        RuleFor(p => p.Value).Length(3, 10).When(d => d.Id == 7).WithMessage("Enter Minimum Monthly Amount of an account to report!!").NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Value).Length(3, 10).When(d => d.Id == 8).WithMessage("Enter Minimum Monthly Amount of an account to report!!!").NotEmpty();
    }

    private bool BeAValidDate(DateTime date)
    {
        return !date.Equals(default(DateTime));
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
```

}

```
<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Bank Parameters (FATCA)</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Parameter" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Parameter" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Parameter" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Value" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Value" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Value" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: why not use DTO or ViewModel?

Comment: never heard of DTO in any tutorial or video of validation neither of those pop up.
Also I have a View of this Model in my project

Comment: is your project is splitted into multiple libraries